# Is it possible to get hosted web apps into the Apple App Store (2016)?

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, hybrid

I have a hosted web application, can i use cordova to package just the index and send all request to hosted web application?
All cordova sample i see the web component is getting packaged into the app. Does app store  allow to just create a native shell and direct login and other request to hosted web application.

I want to mainly use the mobile web app hosted on the server and use cordova only as an frame to view the hosted app so that any updates would propagate 
to all the devices without having to go through the app store.

Some older post say we can not do it. Is this still the case, has anyone tried this?

Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should be possible. You have to provide needed credentials like login information in the additional information section at iTunesConnect. The review team needs them to test your App.

Comment: It's not allowed, but you can try

Comment: No its not allowed, its stated in the review guidelines clear as day. It is also something that you simply shouldn't do. As an iOS developer and a user, there is nothing I hate more than downloading an "app" that is just a shell. Web apps belong on the web, native apps belong on the phone ... thats just life

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's review guidelines, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Apple's App Store Review Guidelines page there is a section (2.12) that says:

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

Site link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

In my opinion you can try to submit, but be prepared to get rejected.